# Setting font size for a DropDownListFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set the font size of the data inside a DropDownListFor.  I can set the size for all the other text in the grid, however, I can't seem to control the text inside the DropDownListFor.

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(listitem => item.AttendStatusType, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["status"], "Value", "Text",item.AttendStatusType), new { @class="attendStatusList", id = "student" + item.Id + "attendStatus" })%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
```

I have tried many different things but nothing seems to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out how to do it, here was the solution:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(listitem => item.AttendStatusType, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["status"], "Value", "Text",item.AttendStatusType), new { @class="attendStatusList", id = "student" + item.Id + "attendStatus",style="font-size:90%;" })%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
```

by simply adding the ,style="font-size:90%;" it worked.  Should have worked using the Site.css or div wrapper, but neither one of those worked.